# How to write UDFs in pyspark for making API calls with quota limits?

Tags: pandas, pyspark

I have below code here which is written in non-distributed fashion using traditional pandas loop. I am sure that `for` loop is a bad practise to iterate over the pandas dataframes. Essentially, I am looping over the `text` records one by one in the IMDB reviews dataset and trying to get a sentiment score and magnitude for every text in the current row.

Here is the code

```
from google.cloud import language
from google.cloud.language import enums
from google.cloud.language import types
import pandas as pd
import datetime

def compute_sentiment_score(text,client):
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.score)

def compute_sentiment_magnitude(text,client):
    document = types.Document(content=text,type=enums.Document.Type.PLAIN_TEXT, language='en')
    sentiment = client.analyze_sentiment(document=document).document_sentiment
    return str(sentiment.magnitude)

import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="/path-to-file.json"

imdb_reviews = pd.read_csv('imdb_reviews.csv', header=None, names=['input1', 'input2'], encoding= "ISO-8859-1")

imdb_reviews.head()

    input1                                         input2
0   first think another Disney movie, might good, ...   1
1   Put aside Dr. House repeat missed, Desperate H...   0
2   big fan Stephen King's work, film made even gr...   1
3   watched horrid thing TV. Needless say one movi...   0
4   truly enjoyed film. acting terrific plot. Jeff...   1
```

Here is that ugly loop - right now I am running this for only 100 iterations but actual records are 25k

```
client = language.LanguageServiceClient() # establish client connection

print(datetime.datetime.now())
for i in range(100):
    imdb_reviews.loc[i, 'score'] = compute_sentiment_score(str(imdb_reviews.loc[i,'input1']),client)
    imdb_reviews.loc[i,'magnitude'] = compute_sentiment_magnitude(str(imdb_reviews.loc[i,'input1']),client)
print(datetime.datetime.now())

2020-09-09 00:39:11.312789 # start time of loop
2020-09-09 00:40:17.167283 # end time of loop
```

So to compute this for 100 records it takes around 60 seconds. If I go at same scale, it would obviously take a lot of time to process this.

Is there a way to do this in pyspark in distributed fashion? I tried the same with pypsark previously using `UDF` but I was ending up making 1000s of connection objects in less than a minute and Google Cloud has request quota limit. Hence I was getting failure like below -

```
"grpc_message":"Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute per user' of service 'language.googleapis.com' for consumer
```

Answer (score 0):

The service quotas will always be a bottleneck, no matter what you do.

That being said you can try two approaches:

1. check whether the api you are using has an async version. This will allow you to be maximally efficient when working on a single process: you can batch the requests and send them concurrently (of to the service quota)
2. In spark, instead of using a udf, you should use mapPartitions. This will allow you to create a connection *per partition* instead of *per record* which will greatly speed things up. You can handle the number of parallel requests by controlling the number of partitions you have (repartition). I am not worried about the memory pressure here since the data set is not very large.

The ultimate solution will combine (1) and (2) but not all apis support async operations.

Comment: thank you for the answer. Can you throw some links which show code examples of how to use `mapPartitions` ? That would help me as a starting point.